# How to install GDAL version 3.0 on Windows in order to generate GeoPDF with Qgis 3.10?

Tags: gdal, qgis-3, geopdf

I am very enthusiastic to create some GeoPDFs using the new version of Qgis 3.10 on Windows. Unfortunately, using the OSGeo Installer, the newest gdal package version proposed is 2.4.1, which is annoying considering that the minimal required version to create GeoPDFs is the 3.0.

As described in the documentation here https://gdal.org/download.html#current-releases, I tried to install the latest gdal version through Anaconda client. Here again the latest package available is 2.3.3.

In googling on the web I also found that site => http://www.gisinternals.com/development.php which gives some links to download gdal 3.0. Despite the fact that the installation is possible that way (I guess), I do not get it. Besides, how could we be sure that the gdal installation that way will be "clean" and correctly working in QGIS 3.10?

I really think that new feature of creation GeoPDFs is a real improvement. I guess I will not be an isolate case, and this is really too bad that it does not work "out-of-the-box". Maybe I am also too eager to use that function, and we have to wait a few dasy/weeks to have the new gdal 3.0 automatically suggested in the OSGeo Installer...

Could someone explain the way to install this gdal 3.0 on Windows in order to create GeoPDFs with Qgis 3.10?